# trying to to get specifically ordered data from .txt and then converting and storing it to double or string arrays at visual basic

Tags: vb.net, vba, visual-studio-2008

I am trying, for several days, to take specifically ordered data from a .txt file and then convert and store it to double or string arrays

the data is stored in the file in this way:

```
1 0 1 0 >= 15
0 1 0 1 >= 28
1 1 0 0 <= 30 
0 0 3 1 <= 22 
-1 0 2 0 <= 0
```

(one line after the other with no blank lines between them)

and my code for this goes like:

```vb
Using stream As System.IO.FileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead("C:\Users\user\Desktop\test_new.txt")

            Using reader As New System.IO.StreamReader(stream)
                Dim lineCount = File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\user\Desktop\test_new.txt").Length

                Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()
                Dim aryTextFile() As String
                Dim operator1() As String
                Dim variables(,) As Double
                Dim results() As Double
                Dim counter3 As Integer
                counter3 = 0
                NRows = lineCount

                While (line IsNot Nothing)

                    Dim columns = line.Split(" ")
                    aryTextFile = line.Split(" ")

                    line = reader.ReadLine()

                    NVars = columns.Length - 3

                    For j = 0 To UBound(aryTextFile) - 3

                        variables(counter3, j) = CDbl(aryTextFile(j))


                    Next j
                    For j = NVars To UBound(aryTextFile) - 2

                        operator1(counter3) = CStr(aryTextFile(j))


                    Next j

                    For j = UBound(aryTextFile) - 2 To UBound(aryTextFile) - 1

                        results(counter3) = CDbl(aryTextFile(j))


                    Next j
                    counter3 = counter3 + 1
                End While

            End Using
        End Using
```

I'm getting warnings which result in errors ofc.

> 1. Variable 'variables' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at
>      runtime.  C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio
>      2008\Projects\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\Form1.vb    230 25  WindowsApplication1
> 2. Variable 'operator1' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at
>      runtime.  C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio
>      2008\Projects\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\Form1.vb    236 25  WindowsApplication1
> 3. Variable 'results' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at
>      runtime.  C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio
>      2008\Projects\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\Form1.vb    243 25  WindowsApplication1

So what am I doing wrong and how can I fix it

note: data is saved from dynamic matrixes, so it can be a lot bigger than the displayed example (several lines with several columns), and that is the reason I'm trying to program it, in order to save me some lab time of copying and pasting it manually...

thanks in advance, 
Viktor

p.s. if another member or admin can indicate an older post about my question, that would also be very helpful, but I am reading posts for the last 4 days in similar questions and I couldn't find something working for me

p.s.2 since is my first post, I have also tried to attach the project and I couldn't find a way :)

Comment: is it VB.NET or VBA - 2 different things; the messages mean what they say.  `Dim variables(,) As Double` declares an array but does not create an instance.

Comment: `lineCount` will tell you how big they should be, but your calls to `reader.ReadLine()` will fail because you read ALL the lines from the file up at the top.  Use `ReadAllLines` to read the file into an array and process that instead.

Comment: the reason i need to read all lines (and linecount) is to know the precise size of the datatables i am going to form in my next steps of the projects (nvars and nrows excist for this reason) the second reader which reads from line to line tries to split the data in order to create 3 arrays

Comment: you can get the size from the array of lines read in, then process the array of lines instead of the StreamReader

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the dimensions of your arrays before trying to use them.

If you don't know what the size will be use a list instead.

```
    'No defined size - Warning
    Dim array1() As String
    'Error when trying to access
    array1(4) = "Testing"

    'Defined size 
    Dim array2(10) As String
    array2(5) = "Testing"
```